# React: MUI Dialog component close and open on submitting form when getting error

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, frontend

I'm trying to show error on the dialog in case the service return it any, but every time i hit the submit button the whole dialog component close and open immediately and it resets. I'm trying to use the useRef()  hook but with no success.
any suggestion how i can handle this situation?

Using useRef hook and useImperativeHandle on my component

SOURCE CODE OF THE DIALOG COMPONENT

```html
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { useState, useRef, forwardRef, useImperativeHandle } from "react";
import { m } from 'framer-motion';
// @mui
import { Dialog, Box, Paper, DialogTitle, IconButton } from '@mui/material';
import CloseIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Close';
//
import { varFade } from './variants';
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

function CustomDialogTitle(props) {
  const { children, onClose, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <DialogTitle sx={{ m: 0, p: 2 }} {...other}>
      {children}
      {onClose ? (
        <IconButton
          aria-label="close"
          onClick={onClose}
          sx={{
            position: 'absolute',
            right: 8,
            top: 8,
            color: (theme) => theme.palette.grey[500],
          }}
        >
          <CloseIcon />
        </IconButton>
      ) : null}
    </DialogTitle>
  );
}

const DialogAnimate = ({dialogTitle, variants, onClose, children, sx, ...other}, ref) => {

  DialogAnimate.propTypes = {
    dialogTitle: PropTypes.string,
    variants: PropTypes.any,
    onClose: PropTypes.func,
    children: PropTypes.any,
    sx: PropTypes.any
  }

  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const innerRef = useRef();

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    openDialog: () => setOpen(true),
    closeDialog: () => setOpen(false)
  }));

  return (
    <Dialog ref={innerRef}
            fullWidth
            maxWidth="xs"
            open={open}
            onClose={onClose}
            PaperComponent={(props) => (
              <Box
                component={m.div}
                {...(variants ||
                  varFade({
                    distance: 120,
                    durationIn: 0.32,
                    durationOut: 0.24,
                    easeIn: 'easeInOut',
                  }).inUp)}
                sx={{
                  width: '100%',
                  height: '100%',
                  display: 'flex',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                }}>
                <Box onClick={handleClose} sx={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', position: 'fixed' }} />
                <Paper sx={sx} {...props}>
                  {props.children}
                </Paper>
              </Box>
            )}
            {...other}>
      <CustomDialogTitle id="customized-dialog-title"
                         onClose={onClose}>
        {dialogTitle}
      </CustomDialogTitle>
      {children}
    </Dialog>
  );
};

export default forwardRef(DialogAnimate);
```

INVOCATION OF THE CODE

```html
import { useRef } from 'react';
import { Button } from '@mui/material';
import Iconify from '../../components/Iconify';

export default function PriceForm() {
  const dialogRef = useRef();
  
  const handleOpenModal = () => {
    dialogRef.current.openDialog();
  }
  
  const handleCloseModal = () => {
    dialogRef.current.closeDialog();
  }
  
  return (
    <Button startIcon={<Iconify icon="eva:plus-fill" />}
            size="small"
            variant="outlined"
            onClick={() => handleOpenModal()}> Create Price
    </Button>
    <DialogAnimate dialogTitle="Add Price" 
                   ref={dialogRef}>
      <PriceNewForm onSubmitEvent={() => handleCloseModal()}/>
    </DialogAnimate>
  )
}
```

FORM INSIDE DIALOG

```html
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { useEffect, useMemo, useState } from 'react';
import { useSnackbar } from 'notistack';
// form
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup';
// @mui
import { LoadingButton } from '@mui/lab';
import { Container, Grid, Stack, Alert, AlertTitle } from '@mui/material';
// redux
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from '../../redux/store';
// components
import { FormProvider, RHFAutocomplete, RHFTextField } from '../../components/hook-form';
import { endLoading, savePrice } from '../../redux/slices/item/price';

PriceNewForm.propTypes = {
  onSubmitEvent: PropTypes.func
}

export default function PriceNewForm({ onSubmitEvent }) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar();
  const { currentItem } = useSelector((state) => state.item);
  const { error } = useSelector((state) => state.price);
  const { stores } = useSelector((state) => state.store);
  const { exchangeRatelist } = useSelector((state) => state.exchangeRate);
  const [openAlert, setOpenAlert] = useState(false);

  const priceSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    storeId: Yup.string().required('Shop required'),
    priceWithTax: Yup.number().required('Price required').moreThan(0, 'Price must be higher than 0.00'),
    currency: Yup.string().required('Currency is required'),
  });

  const defaultValues = useMemo(
    () => ({
      itemId: currentItem.id,
      tax: currentItem.tax,
      storeId: '',
      currency: '',
      priceWithTax: 0,
    }),
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    []
  );

  const methods = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(priceSchema),
    defaultValues,
  });

  const {
    watch,
    setValue,
    handleSubmit,
    getValues,
    formState: { isSubmitting },
  } = methods;

  const values = watch();

  const onSubmit = async () => {
    const data = { ...getValues(), priceWithTax: Number(getValues().priceWithTax) };
    dispatch(savePrice(data))
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 201) {
          enqueueSnackbar(`Price was saved.`);
          dispatch(endLoading());
          onSubmitEvent(true);
        } 
        else {
          enqueueSnackbar(response.errors.price, { variant: 'error' });
        }
      });
  };

  return (
    <FormProvider methods={methods}
                  onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <Container maxWidth={false}>
          <Stack direction="column"
                 justifyContent="center"
                 spacing={2}>
            <RHFAutocomplete name="storeId"
                             label="SHOP"
                             options={stores.data} />
            <RHFAutocomplete name="currency"
                             label="CURRENCY"
                             options={exchangeRatelist.data}
                             tagName="currency" />
            <RHFTextField type="number"
                          name="priceWithTax"
                          label="PRICE"
                          placeholder="0.00"
                          InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
                          value={getValues('priceWithTax') === 0 ? '' : getValues('priceWithTax')}
                          onChange={(event) => setValue('priceWithTax', event.target.value)}
                          InputProps={{
                            type:'number',
                            inputProps: {
                              style: { textAlign: 'right' }
                            }
                          }} />
            {openAlert && 
              (<Alert severity="error"
                      onClose={() => setOpenAlert(false)}>
                <AlertTitle>{error?.message}</AlertTitle>
                {error?.errors.price}
              </Alert>)
            }
          </Stack>
          <LoadingButton type="submit"
                         variant="contained"
                         size="large"
                         fullWidth 
                         sx={{ my: 3 }}
                         loading={isSubmitting}> CREATE PRICE
          </LoadingButton>
        </Container>
      </Grid>
    </FormProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Why don't you post the source texts of your question here and not as images? I think this way you will get an answer faster.

Comment: thanks for the advice @MaxAlex, post was updated

Comment: Try changing your function like this: const handleClose = (e) => { e.stopPropagation(); setOpen(false) }